# Apache NIFI getMongo An unexpected error has occurred: The specified data reference URI is not valid

Tags: apache-nifi

in Apache NiFi, when configuring the GetMongo processor, I encounter an error while reading data from flowfile

All connection data to the database is entered correctly.[Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CKh3V.png)
[Connections](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wRuZW.png)
The query is executed correctly.
However, when viewing the content of the flowfile, the following error occurs:
[An unexpected error has occurred: The specified data reference URI is not valid.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gbvk5.png)
Both when downloading data and viewing the already downloaded file, the data is correct.
[Download file and view from Notepad++](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YmALB.png)
How can I resolve this error:
An unexpected error has occurred: The specified data reference URI is not valid.

I tried to check connections